# Latex: section title on the left

Tags: latex

I have some problem with Latex with section titles. I would like to do something of this:

```
section title1 |text...
               |text...
               |text..
               |text..
               |text
section title2 |text...
```

How could I do this effect? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: The best fit would be a two columns layout with only the section headings in the left column. But you won't have control over the width of the columns if your sections are required to wrap around pages (that is, both columns will have the same width, which is probably not what you like).
If your sections fit on a single page then consider minipage or vwcol.

Comment: Tip: For LaTeX questions you can also take a look at the sister site (http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indent the whole section text that follows the heading with the changepage package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\section{section heading}
\begin{adjustwidth}{30mm}{0mm}
section text line one

section text line two
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{section two heading}
...
\end{document}
```

Which gives you something like

```
section heading
          section text line one
          section text line two

section two heading
...
```